# Pack URI to resources in referenced assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've been banging my head over this for some time, but for the love of god, I just cant figure out whats wrong with my uri. Maybe someone could help.

I'm developing an addin for a third-party software (means I have no access to App.config and cant modify application itself). The addin is located in a folder that differs from location of the exe file. I have a wpf window located in MyAddin.View.dll. Recently I've decided to move all WPF resources in a separate assembly (called UI.Shared). I've added UI.Shared.dll as a reference to MyAddin.View.dll, I've also modified my pack uri inside MyAddin.View.dll window to this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary
         Source="pack://application:,,,/UI.Shared;component/Styles/Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</Window.Resources>
```

I've made sure that Style.xaml Build Action is set to Resource. The UI.Shared.dll is located in the same folder as MyAddin.View.dll (but both of them are ***NOT*** in the same folder as application executable). Everything works fine at design time. But during run-time, I get: 
 ***"Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw an exception."***
 And the inner exception says:
***Could not load file or assembly 'UI.Shared, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.***

Everything worked just fine before I've moved resources into a separate assembly:(. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URI is fine.

I've had a similar problem when calling WPF windows from VBA: WPF was unable to find the referenced resources, since the main process was started from a different directory. The solution I found might be useful for your case as well:

- You attach an event handler to the [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If the assembly is not found, you search for it in the add-in directory.

Here is some (untested) C# example code, inspired by some VB.NET code that we have in production use:

```
// Do this when your add-in starts
var addinAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, e) =>
{
    var missing = new AssemblyName(e.Name);

    // Sometimes the WPF assembly resolver cannot even find the executing assembly...
    if (missing.FullName == addinAssembly.FullName)
        return addinAssembly;

    var addinFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(addinAssembly.Location);
    var missingPath = Path.Combine(addinFolder, missing.Name + ".dll");

    // If we find the DLL in the add-in folder, load and return it.
    if (File.Exists(missingPath))
        return Assembly.LoadFrom(missingPath);

    // nothing found
    return null;
};
```

Comment: Well, this works, but I was hoping there would be a cleaner solution. If not, I will mark this as answer.

Comment: This is about the cleanest implementation of AssemblyResolve I've seen. :)