# Calling a stylesheet from WPF page

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, stylesheet, datatemplate

I have a really peculiar situation and I'm a bit lost to be honest. I have a WPF Application that is run from within a Windows Form Application. In order to run this I am creating the MainWindow.xaml from my WinForms code.
This means that my App.xaml is never getting hit.

I have tried all the various methods for using a stylesheet in my Application.xaml but because this is not run i think i need to call my stylesheet from each page(similar to web).

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="TextStyle.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

This is the code that i see so much online and fair enough if i call it from my App.xaml it will work in the designer but because at run time its never hit so it wont work.

I have tried even instantiating the App.xaml file from my WPF application but I'm not sure if I messed it up or it just doesn't work but it didn't like it

Is there something similar that can be called on either WPF pages or windows?

Sorry I'm new to WPF and can work with the basics but I'm banging my head against the wall on this one

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does the problem also occur if you use the full pack URI to the source, i.e., `<ResourceDictionary Source="/MyApplication;component/Resources/TextStyle.xaml" />`? Replace `MyApplication` with the name of your assembly, keep `;component` and replace `Resources` with the name of your directory.

Comment: Alternatively, if the Windows Forms application is located in a different directory, it might be an issue of the assembly resolver: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20495980/87698

Answer (score 0):

App.xaml does not run when hosting WPF components on WinForm. Have a look at 
http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/10/05/managing-application-resources-when-wpf-is-hosted/ for few ways on how to manage resources in hosted WPF applications.

In your case i think the issue is with the way you set the in the Source attribute, try using pack url, e.g.,

```
<Page.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary>
         <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/theNameOfTheResourceAssembly;component/resourceName.xaml" />
         </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

the resource should also be formatted as such:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    x:Class="theNameOfTheResourceAssembly.resourceName">
   ...resource contents
</ResourceDictionary>
```